# mulit netsting `mutable` in Google proto

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, mutable, proto

I have proto file, saying that,

```
message RecommendInfo{
 repeated RecommendItem vec_item = 1;  
}

message Response{
 RecommendInfo recomInfo = 1;
}
```

I want to produce type `Response` response.
So I use following code,

```
Response response;
*(recommendResponse.recominfo().mutable_vec_item()) = {items.begin(), items.end()};
LOG_INFO << response.DebugString();
```

But there gets empty vecitem. I thought there existed `Response` object on stack. `Response` object includes `RecommendInfo` object on the stack. Because I want to change `items` inside `RecommendInfo` object. So I use `mutable_vec_item()` to set `items`.

I try

```
*(recom_response.mutable_recominfo()->mutable_vecitem()) = {items.begin(), items.end()};
```

The code works and print complete `RecommendInfo` object including `vec_item`.

I can't explain it clearly. When I try to change `recom_response.recominfo()`, it seems to be wrong. However,isn't `RecommendInfo` an object on stack? And I just want to modify `vec_item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying `vecitem` modifies the `RecommendInfo` it belongs to.

So in order to modify the content of `vecitem`, you have to be operating on a modifiable (aka mutable) `RecommendInfo`. That's why you have to use `mutable_recominfo()` instead of `recominfo()`.